# How to show a div next to the hovered element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say i have **several** div's like these:

EDIT:

```
<div class="ProfilePic">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="lib/css/img/profile_pic1.png" alt="" class="ProfilePicImg"/>
    </a>

    <div class="PopupBox" style="display:none;"> ... </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to hover over the image `.ProfilePicImg` and show a another div relatively to it.

The box to popup on hover is set to `position:absolute`. And the `.ProfilePic`'s position is relative. Just like it should be.

I have tried different solutions, but in vain... And I have also searched around here on StackOverflow...

Does anyone have a trick for this?

**P.S.** I don't want the popup box to show on each of the `.ProfilePic` div's I have...

**EDIT2:** It seems jQuery's `.find()` traversal function was the key to fetch the *specific* .PopupBox i wanted to show, instead of the all.

Comment: `I don't want the popup box to show on each...` What are the conditions under which popup will show? Can you show the complete markup including the div to be shown?

Comment: The condition is that when I hover my mouse over **__one__** of the `.ProfilePic` DIV's, I only want the popup box to show next to it -- even though it's hidden and specified inside each of the many `.ProfilePic` DIV's.

Comment: can you show us where you are keeping the popup box?

Comment: I know my information was limited... I've edited to clarify your question...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I haven't tested the code but is this what you are looking for?

```
$(".ProfilePicImg").hover(function(){
    var divToShow = $(this).parent("a").siblings("div.PopupBox");
    divToShow.css({
        display: "block",
        position: "absolute",
        left: ($(this).offset().left + $(this).width()) + "px",
        top: $(this).offset().top + "px"
    });
},
function(){
    $("div.PopupBox").hide();   
});
```

Comment: How do you get `$("#divToShow");`?

Comment: I'm assuming that there is a single div displaying dynamic contents according to the hovered image. But yea, the example i've given is only for displaying the div, not the content. Maybe i've assumed wrong :D.

Comment: Giving you credit for leading me to the answer. See my edit's for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use CSS positioning?

```
#PopupBox {
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #456789;
}
```